# Logout of GMail account using SMTP

Tags: android, smtp, jakarta-mail, logout

I'm sending mail using SMTP. Sending mail works well. However, I want to use logout on button click so that I can logout of my account. How can I logout of the account? Is there a method for logout?

Here is some code I use:

```
   public void Mail(String user, String pass) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(FROM_MAILID,PASSWORD);
        }
        });
    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM_MAILID));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(TO_MAILID));
        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");     
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();     
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/wallpaper.jpg"));
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName("image.png");
        messageBodyPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.ATTACHMENT);
        messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID","<vogue>");
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        message.setContent(multipart);
        Transport.send(message);

        Log.d("sent","mail sent...");
    }catch(AuthenticationFailedException afe){
        Log.d("wrong","wrong passwrd....");
    }catch(AddressException ae){


    }catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183906/programmatically-logout-from-gmail-via-oauth

Comment: Can't you just delete the `JavaMail` object or the `Session` object?

Comment: how to delete session then??

Answer (score 0):

Add a finally block with session.close(): after your last catch statement:

```
} finally {
    session.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you've made a bunch of the [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes); clean them up.

There's no need to "logout" because you're only "logged in" for the time it takes to send the message.  When Transport.send finishes, the connection is closed and you're logged out.

Comment: can i write separate code just for login? after successful login i want to send mail.what should i write just for login?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601503/login-gmail-checking-correct-user-id-and-password-and-then-sending-mail-in-andr